# Calculating percentage

Tags: php, mysql

I've got a leader board in PHP/MySQL that displays users by percentage descending. I calculate the percentage:

```
$percentage = ($correct / $total) * 100
```

My question is how to factor in number of attempts (risk) so that let's say a user with 1 out of 1 for 100% isn't above a user with say 75 out of 80 for 93.8%

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

That's just part of how you order the results

```
SELECT (correct / $total) * 100 AS percent FROM table ORDER BY percent DESC, attempts ASC;
```

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how big an influence the risk factor should have!
Just guessing here but I believe not dividing by total would result in too big a number so various solutions could be implemented a few suggestions could be to multiply the result by (1 + ($total / 100)) or to further reduce the impact of each new attempt you could multiply by (1 + (sqrt($total) / 100)) - experiment with other values, 100 was used just as an example or other non-linear functions like log.

Answer (score 0):

Compute the percent that an average user has, and give each user a baseline of 10 average attempts (for some value of 10).

Say the average was 50%. Then you'd compute `$percentage = ($correct+5)/($total+10)*100`. Users who consistently do well will still come out on top eventually (because their successes will overwhelm the average score you started them with, but a user with a good start won't jump to the top).

e.g Under this system, your first user would now have a score of `6/11 = 54%` and your second user would have `80 / 90 = 88%`.